# Is it possible to add code to an existing method when using Swig to build a C# wrapper for C++ code?

Tags: c#, c++, swig

When using Swig to wrap C++ code, it is possible to [add methods to the native C++ type](http://www.swig.org/Doc2.0/SWIGDocumentation.html#Java_class_extension) using `%extend`. It is possible to [add methods to the C# wrapper class](http://www.swig.org/Doc2.0/CSharp.html#csharp_extending_proxy_class) using `%typemap(cscode)`.

Where a method already exists in the wrapper class, **is there a way to add additional lines of code?**

For example, my C# wrapper method looks like this:

```
  public void ItemChanged(CollectionObject collectionObject, string propertyName) {
    mynamespacePINVOKE.mynamespace_DataObjectCollection_ItemChanged(swigCPtr, CollectionObject.getCPtr(collectionObject), propertyName);
    if (mynamespacePINVOKE.SWIGPendingException.Pending) throw mynamespacePINVOKE.SWIGPendingException.Retrieve();
  }
```

I'd like to add a line of code:

```
  public void ItemChanged(CollectionObject collectionObject, string propertyName) {
    mynamespacePINVOKE.mynamespace_DataObjectCollection_ItemChanged(swigCPtr, CollectionObject.getCPtr(collectionObject), propertyName);
    if (mynamespacePINVOKE.SWIGPendingException.Pending) throw mynamespacePINVOKE.SWIGPendingException.Retrieve();
    **insert my line of code here**
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to write your own version you're going to need to make sure it doesn't clash with the default one. I think the easiest way to do this would be to make `ItemChanged` private/protected using `%csmethodmodifiers` and `%rename` to hide the default wrapped version that gets generated. Once it's hidden.

You can then safely write your own version of `ItemChanged` using a cscode typemap that firstly calls the private version and then calls your additional code as you desire.

This is by far the cleanest way of solving the problem - the only way you're able to inject code directly into the generated code is as part of the argument/return value marshalling - setting up the arguments that get passed in, cleaning up after or handling the return value. Messing with one of those typemaps to inject some code would be fairly messy.