# Add more than one method to Java class

Tags: java, c++, macros, swig

I need to add a method to a class for some classes on c++ side. for example, i have class A B C D on c++ side and class A B C D on java side generated by swig, in class D(java side) i need to add 3 methods that looks like :

```
public abstract class D {
    public abstract void do(A a);
    public abstract void do(B b);
    public abstract void do(C c);
}
```

I wrote a swig macro to do that

%define MYMACRO(CLASSTYPE)

```
%typemap(javacode) D %{
  public void do(CLASSTYPE item);
%}
%enddef

MYMACRO(A);
MYMACRO(B);
MYMACRO(C);
```

but it only works on the last macro, I tried  **%typemap(javabody)**  and it doesn't work either.
Please help me

Comment: Does it shows any error?

Comment: swig shows no error/warning, class D turns out like : public abstract class D {
    public abstract void do(C c);
} if last macro is MYMACRO(C)

Comment: seems like %typemap(javacode) overwrites

Comment: do i have to modify class D manually?

Comment: You're correct in your assessment that it replaces rather than appends the javacode. (This seems to be a fairly frequently requested feature). There is a workaround you can use if you're desperate though: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12103206/is-it-possible-to-add-text-to-an-existing-typemap-in-swig?lq=1