# Add code to automatically generated class in SWIG

Tags: c#, c++, swig, dllimport

I'm trying to find a way to add code to swig generated functions. I have used typemaps to extend classes, but can't find anything in the documentation about extending specific functions.

Given the following swig interface file:

```
%module Test
%{
#include "example.h"
%}

%typemap(cscode) Example %{
    bool 64bit = SizeOf(typeof(System.IntPtr)) == 8;
    static string Path = 64bit ? "/...Path to 64 bit dll.../" : 
                                 "/...Path to 32 bit dll.../";
%}

%include "example.h"
```

I get the following C# code:

```
public class MyClass : global::System.IDisposable {
    ...
    bool 64bit = SizeOf(typeof(System.IntPtr)) == 8;
    static string Path = 64bit ? "/...Path to 64 bit dll.../" : 
                                 "/...Path to 32 bit dll.../";

    ...
    public static SomeObject Process(...) {     // Function defined in example.h
                                               <- I would like to add some code here.
        SomeObject ret = new SomeObject(...);

    }
    ...
}
```

I would like to add some code to the function Process, this code is a call to `SetDllDirectory(Path)` which loads the correct dll depending on the platform type. This needs to happen inside the `Process()` call.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Never having used swig (and based on what I just googled) it seems that you want to inject C# specific code (`SetDllDirectory()`) during the translation from the preexisting C++ source file.  If that is right, then I think you have to rearrange your C++ code to accommodate that injection. EG Creating a stub virtual function call in `Process()` C++ code which you can later override once you are in the C# realm.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it possible to add code to an existing method when using Swig to build a C# wrapper for C++ code?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11286913/is-it-possible-to-add-code-to-an-existing-method-when-using-swig-to-build-a-c-sh)

Comment: @PeterM That's the sort of approach I was thinking of, but couldn't find a way to actually make it work. Flexo has given an alternative way to inject C# code directly which I'll try out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can generate the code you're looking for using `%typemap(csout)`. It's a bit of a hack though, and you'll need to copy some of the existing typemap for SWIGTYPE (which is a generic place holder) that can be found in csharp.swg

So for example, given a header file example.h:

```
struct SomeObject {};

struct MyClass {
  static SomeObject test();
};
```

You can then write the following SWIG interface file:

```
%module Test
%{
#include "example.h"
%}

%typemap(csout,excode=SWIGEXCODE) SomeObject {
    // Some extra stuff here
    $&csclassname ret = new $&csclassname($imcall, true);$excode
    return ret;
}

%include "example.h"
```

Which produces:

```
public static SomeObject test() {
    // Some extra stuff here
    SomeObject ret = new SomeObject(TestPINVOKE.MyClass_test(), true);
    return ret;
}
```

If you want to generate that for all return types, not just things which return SomeObject you'll have a bit more work to do for all the variants of csout.

Comment: This looks great, thanks. I'll give it a go and see if I can get a working version together.

Answer (score 0):

Section [20.8.7 of the SWIG docs](http://www.swig.org/Doc3.0/SWIGDocumentation.html#CSharp_extending_proxy_class) shows how to use `typemap(cscode)` to extend generated classes.

Comment: That allows you to add extra methods, but not extend an existing method.

Comment: I believe I saw a post that uses `cscode` with `%ignore` and `%rename` but I cant find it now...